# Exception occured while tried to use 'InsertBefore' of XmlDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I was trying to insert a xml node before another xmlnode and I have got an exception saying "The reference node is not a child of this node."

This is my initial xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sampleData>
    <otherNodes></otherNodes>
  </sampleData>
</Details>
```

I wanted to insert following xml datas(b:dataTobeInserted1,b:dataTobeInserted2 and b:dataTobeInserted3) as a Child of **Details** but before **sampleData**.

Details1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataInserted1 xmlns:b="http://example.com/data">
  <b:dataTobeInserted1>
    <b:otherDetails1></b:otherDetails1>
  </b:dataTobeInserted1>
</DataInserted1>
```

Details2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataInserted2 xmlns:b="http://example.com/data">
  <b:dataTobeInserted2>
    <b:otherDetails2></b:otherDetails2>
  </b:dataTobeInserted2>
</DataInserted2>
```

Details3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataInserted3 xmlns:b="http://example.com/data">
  <b:dataTobeInserted3>
    <b:otherDetails3></b:otherDetails3>
  </b:dataTobeInserted3>
</DataInserted3>
```

I want my Output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:b="http://example.com/data">
  <b:dataTobeInserted1>
    <b:otherDetails1></b:otherDetails1>
  </b:dataTobeInserted1>
  <b:dataTobeInserted2>
    <b:otherDetails2></b:otherDetails2>
  </b:dataTobeInserted2>
  <b:dataTobeInserted3>
    <b:otherDetails3></b:otherDetails3>
  </b:dataTobeInserted3>
  <sampleData>
    <otherNodes></otherNodes>
  </sampleData>
</Details>
```

This is what I did to achieve my desired output.

```
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(@"..\..\initial-Doc.xml");

    xmldoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:b", "http://example.com/data");


        XmlDocument detail1 = new XmlDocument();
        detail1.Load(@"..\..\DataToBeInserted1.xml");
        XmlNode detail1Node = xmldoc.ImportNode(detail1.DocumentElement, true);

        XmlDocument detail2 = new XmlDocument();
        detail2.Load(@"..\..\DataToBeInserted2.xml");
        XmlNode detail2Node = xmldoc.ImportNode(detail2.DocumentElement, true);

        XmlDocument detail3 = new XmlDocument();
        detail3.Load(@"..\..\DataToBeInserted3.xml");
        XmlNode detail3Node = xmldoc.ImportNode(detail3.DocumentElement, true);

    xmldoc.InsertBefore(detail1Node, xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
    xmldoc.InsertBefore(detail2Node, xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
    xmldoc.InsertBefore(detail3Node, xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

    xmldoc.Save(@"..\..\initial-Doc-new.xml");
```

Is the new namespace is causing the problem?Please tell me where I went wrong.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks to me like the problem is exactly what the exception says: "The reference node is not a child of this node." The only tricky part is figuring out which nodes they're referring to. :-)

Here "**this node**" means the XmlNode whose `InsertBefore()` method you're calling, and "**the reference node**" means the second argument to [InsertBefore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertbefore.aspx)(). So in the following line:

```
xmldoc.InsertBefore(detail1Node, xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
```

It's saying that `xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild` is not a child of `xmldoc`.

Which is true. `xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild` is a child of `xmldoc.DocumentElement`.

So if you change that line to the following, the problem should be fixed:

```
xmldoc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(detail1Node, xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
```

Comment: thanks mate it worked,thanks a lot for the nice explanation for my problem. Appreciate that :)

Comment: @Alex: glad to be of service!

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. I wish this XML doc was a bit clearer

Comment: @KaiCriticallyAcclaimedCooper: I agree, but I'm not sure how it could be phrased more clearly. How would you write the exception message?

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem and also saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy of the node, for you cannot add an xml node from one document to another.

I *think* copying the node using the `CloneNode()` method should be enough, but if that fails you could create a new node from the nodes `InnerXml` or `OuterXml` property.

Comment: If you take a look into output xml you can see that there is a new namespace added to it. is that causing a problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the ImportNode method of the XmlDocument class:

```
XmlNode importedDetailsNode = xmldoc.ImportNode(detail3.DocumentElement, true);
xmldoc.InsertBefore(importedDetailsNode , xmldoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the MSDN documentation.